# When using dollar operator for attribute selectors I get an "Invalid property value" error

Tags: html, css, attributes, selector

I'm trying to use the attribute = value selectors to place icons at pdf links on our website. It is working well for the external links that I've setup but when I try to use it for pdf files I get the "Invalid property value" error.

Over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) indicates the use of $= if the end (suffix) of the href is what I want to match - which it is.

Here is the code I'm using in my css:

```
a[href$=".pdf" i]{
    background-image: url(/images/pdflink.png) no-repeat right top;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the dot in the value by prepending `\`. And escape the escape character if using pre-processor.

Comment: OK, I tried a single \ to escape the period and the error still comes. I tried two \ and then the error goes away. But... The image I want shown isn't showing. My code now looks like this:
`
a[href$="\\.pdf" i]{
 background-image: url(/images/pdflink.png) no-repeat right top;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
`